# TMUX: no space for new pane

Tags: tmux

Consider the TMUX

```
tmux new-session -d -s theSession
for p in {1..30}
do
   echo "Welcome to Pane number #$p"
   tmux split-window -v -p 140 -t theSession
   tmux send-keys -t theSession "./run-exp-scr.sh" Enter
done

tmux attach -t theSession
```

When I run script I get :

```
no space for new pane
```

Any idea how to solve this ?

Answer (score 6):

Googling your error I came across [this mailing list link](https://www.mail-archive.com/tmux-users@googlegroups.com/msg01246.html) which seems to imply you need to tell tmux to relayout things with e.g. `selectl tiled` to ensure there's enough space. Add a `select-layout` call in your loop:

```
tmux split-window -v -p 140 -t theSession
tmux select-layout -t theSession tiled
```